# Mathematics Puzzle - Number Circle

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

The numbers **1**, **6**, **8**, **13**, **15**, and **20** can be placed in the circle below, each
exactly once, so that the sum of each pair of numbers adjacent in the circle is *a
multiple of seven*.

In fact, there is more than one way to arrange the numbers in such a way in the
circle. ***Determine all the different arrangements***. Note that we will consider two
arrangements to be the same if one can be obtained from the other by a series of
reflections and rotations.

[image]

Puzze Source: CEMC

Answer (score 6):

> 1, 8 and 15 are all equal to 1 modulo 7 - call these Group A. 6, 13 and 20 are all congruent to -1 modulo 7 - call these Group B. So any arrangement where Group A are mutually not adjacent to each other will work, and any other arrangement will not work (it would have a sum equal to 2 modulo 7). In any such arrangement, you can pick an arbitrary element of Group B to go between 1 and 8. Then you can pick one of the remaining two elements of Group B to go between 1 and 15. This uniquely determines the configuration, up to rotations and reflections.
>
>  So there are 3*2 = **6** configurations, constructed as described above.